# If Shechina never left the kotel hamaravi can one male Jew say kaddish alone standing in front of the kotel?

Tags: kaddish, kotel-western-wall

If the Shechina never left the kotel hamaravi and if the reason we need a minyan of 10 frum Jewish men to say kaddish is for the Shechina to be present: Why can't a Jew say kaddish alone standing in front of the kotel?

Comment: Both your assumptions are incorrect. Already the Mishna (Avot 3:7) says the shechina can be present with even less than 10 people. In any event no one knows where exactly the kotel hamaaravi of the Temple is nowadays so this wouldn't be practical.

Comment: @DoubleAA So why would you need then 10 Jews to say kaddish (I was told it was to bring down the Divine Presence)

Comment: There are different levels of the Shechinah being present. It's not black and white.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am concerned it is because Kaddish is a "davar bekdusha"

see Orach Chaim 55:

> אוֹמְרִים קַדִּישׁ וְאֵין אוֹמְרִים אוֹתוֹ בְּפָחוֹת מִי׳ זְכָרִים בְּנֵי חוֹרִין גְּדוֹלִים
>
> We say Kaddish but don't say kaddish with less then ten male men who are free and
> adult

See Mishna Berurah:

> קדיש וקדושה וברכו וקה״ת ונשיאת כפים אין אומרים אותו בפחות מעשרה שנא׳
> ונקדשתי בתוך בני ישראל וילפינן בגז״ש דתוך תוך ממרגלים דכתיב עד מתי
> לעדה הרעה הזאת יצאו יהושע וכלב נשאר עשרה וקוראין עדה.

Mishnah Breura says we require 10 men because the Torah tells us that a "davar shebekdusha" needs 10 men from a pasuk which has a gzeirah shava to the spies where there were 10 men (who were the bad "eidah").

My thoughts: perhaps the idea is that the Shechina is there with 10 men (I have heard this before), but perhaps that is not WHY we can say kaddish; rather, we can say kaddish because it is an "eidah" and where there is an "eidah" the Shechinah is as well. Meaning you would need 10 men to be an eidah to say kaddish whether or not the Shechina is there already.

So the Shechina being their is possibly not the reason we can say dvar bekdusha or at least it is not the halachic reason.